# Drive multiple LEDs at different voltages from a low current I/O

Tags: led

I have 2 RGB LEDs that I would like to drive using a uC. All channels draw 20mA, the nominal fwd voltages are 2.0V, 3.2V, 3.2V and the min fwd voltages I've measured are 1.7V, 2.5V, 2.5V

What I would like to do is to be able to control the 3 channels individually using 3 DIOs from the uC in order to mix colours. I would also like to be able to dim the 3 colours globally in analog hardware if possible.

I've attached a schematic of what I was thinking about doing but I have concerns about the two LEDs being different brightness and whether the global control will work. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: Proposed Schematic]

[RGB LED Datasheet](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/CLV1A-FKB-CK1N1G1BB7R4S3/CLV1A-FKB-CK1N1G1BB7R4S3CT-ND/3990811)

Comment: You need to look *veeery* carefully at the third bullet point on the first page as well as the two graphs on the bottom of page 5 of the datasheet.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate.

Comment: The three components have different brightnesses. You should compensate for this rather than putting the same amount of current through all three.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the graphs show they should have relatively equal luminosity at the same 20mA forward current.

Comment: @Passerby: The graphs are normalized to each component's luminosity at 20mA. The absolute luminosity will still be different across the different components, as shown in the order code table on page 4.

Comment: Moot point actually - The OP's expressed *concerns about the two LEDs being different brightness* would need to be addressed by gray correction and empirical data per LED anyway, I'd propose.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the different relative luminosities of the 3 channels. What I'm concerned about is differences in the luminosity of the same diode on the two different packages.

Comment: @spizzak eh, on two rgb leds, the brightness difference would be barely noticeable. You could simply wire some up and compare them, or if you only have two, wire some small 1 or 10 ohm resistors in series with the brighter one to bring the brightness down. Try not to blind yourself when looking at them.

Comment: @spizzak also, are these 6 pin rgb leds, or common anode?

Answer (score 1):

**First**: Two LEDs if operated with identical current, *will* in practice have different intensities, due to manufacturing tolerances even between LEDs from a single batch. This is not easily perceptible when the LEDs are at high intensity, say the 10 to 20 mA range for your 20 mA LEDs, but the differences become very visible as the LEDs are dimmed.

Now, there are a few things that need improvement in the schematic. For instance:

- The potentiometer at the 6.5 Volt rail: 
  Not needed.
  LEDs are current-driven devices. So long as you supply the right polarity of supply and limit the current through each LED chip with an appropriately calculated resistor in series as you have shown, the supply voltage should be the 6.5 Volt line directly.
  Anything above about 4.5 Volts will work - 3.2 Volts for the green and blue LED's maximum, plus some headroom for the transistor's V<sub>CEsat</sub> and for regulation by the resistor.
  .
  Why not use the potentiometer anyway?
  It will need to dissipate power corresponding to the entire current drawn by all 6 LED junctions, so up to 120 mA, times whatever voltage is being dropped across the active part of the potentiometer. That'll require a high power rating pot. Also there will be heat generated on that one part, rather than distributed across several individual current limiting resistors that the schematic already has.
- Why the 6.5 Volt supply? A 5 Volts supply, if available, would reduce wasted power and generated heat at the current limiting resistors.

I am sure others will chime in with other suggestions, but those are a start.

Comment: The potentiometer was intended to be used as physical control for the LED brightness. I don't have any inputs left on the uC so I was trying to find a way to do that but I understand what you're saying and I will have to do this differently.

The system I'm working with has a 6V supply and I figured I might as well use that instead of the regulated supply for the LEDs to keep the 5V cleaner and less loaded.

Comment: @spizzak As you already have microcontroller IO pins driving the transistors, PWM on those pins will permit dimming with much better control, and lower power wastage too.

Comment: Thanks Anindo, the problem I have is that I don't have any way of getting that dimming control to the microcontroller as I have no I/Os left. I have a pot that I'm using to select colour right now but I think I will just repurpose that for dimming and do colour changing randomly.

Comment: @spizzak the same io you are using to drive the transistors, is how you would control the dimming...

Comment: @Passerby I suspect the OP's problem is a lack of IOs for taking a pot position as *input*.

Comment: I understand that but I don't have any way of setting the dim level. Without another input

Comment: Aahhh. Well, there could be some creative options. Dual purpose an adc pin for a switch and a voltage divider, or for multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This will work exactly as you have shown. Keep in mind, you are putting up to (20mA * 6 leds) 120mA through the variable resistor, at 3 to 4 volts, so make sure its a half watt or better pot.

Also, tie the low end of the pot to the wiper, not ground, otherwise you would be connecting a 6.5v / 1k = 6.5mA resistor to ground needlessly.

The pot, while not ideal, would allow manual control, only when the transistors are ON. A better choice would be three small 10k trim pots on the transistor base. You would control the led brightness by adjusting how much current the base of the transistor would receive. Again, the transistors need to be ON for that to work.

Comment: I thought about putting them in series but I want it to run off of a 6V battery as well which wouldn't be enough as the battery starts to drain. Perhaps that's something I can live with.

Comment: LEDs the OP links to are common-anode, and therefore it won't be possible to put them in parallel like you have drawn.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I completely overlooked the link ha.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pot is not going to work effectively.

Imagine you have the pot set for maximum brightness and, you have chosen individual series resistors that match red, green and blue intensities to give you white. OK so far?

When you adjust the pot to dim the LEDs, the red will start to dominate because it needs less voltage across it to maintain current through it. At some point green and blue will extinguish and red will still be shining. You can't colour control this way.

One solution is to use constant current drives to each LED and this is a bit more complex than what you envisage given that you appear to be running out of IO ports.

Another idea is to pulse width modulate (PWM) the IO lines to the LED transistor drivers.

Comment: OP isn't trying to control color with the pot, merely intensity of the entire set of LEDs. Still not a useful approach, of course.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I think he is - "I would also like to be able to dim the 3 colours globally" - that's my conclusion anyway!!

Comment: In [another comment](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87936/drive-multiple-leds-at-different-voltages-from-a-low-current-i-o/87974?noredirect=1#comment173004_87943), OP says "*The potentiometer was intended to be used as physical control for the LED brightness.*" - So I see it as an overall intensity control.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Clearly the OP needs to be clearer (as do possibly his LEDs)!

Comment: Haha! *Clearly* ... *clearer*. :-)

Comment: The intent was to use it as a brightness control for all LEDs. I have decided to forgo one of my other decives and use the potentiometer as in input the microcontroller instead. This way I can use the potentiometer to control brightness by adjusting the PWM.